# maven assembly plugin seems not to respect repository settings

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project which uses the assembly plugin.  When I run the goal "single" it tries to download all the pom files of everything I depend on, and it tries to get them all directly from maven central, even though I have some internal nexus repo configured under `<id>central</id>`.  Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Define a `<mirror>` in your `settings.xml`.

Comment: Why would I need a `<mirror>` if I already have a `<repository>` with `<id>central</id>`?

Comment: hmmm... using a mirror seems to break things even more badly

Comment: Please show your settings.xml configuration.. .and can you explain how you use calling maven-assembly-plugin:single ? Also the appropriate pom file would be helpful...

Comment: let me try to reproduce this with a much smaller pom and settings file

Comment: while trying to create a minimal reproduction I seem to have accidentally made the problem go away.  I think maybe something was missing from my local repo which is now there, so it stopped trying to download it.

Comment: It would be great if you could write it into the answer so others can find that here...

Comment: but I still don't know what the original problem was, or exactly how I fixed it... I don't know why it was looking in maven repo instead of internal one, or how I made it stop... I'd have to delete the artifacts from my local repo by hand and start over, in order to figure that out